# How to store the first token in a variable and append it to the third token?

Tags: java, regex, string, append, tokenize

I have a string with multiple tokens, what i want to do is, i want to store the first token [3:0] in a variable and append it to the third and fourth token and store it in a list.

```
String myStr1 = "[3:0] req0, req1, req2, req3";
```

I want to tokenize the string and get [3:0], req0, req1, req2, req3 in an array and append [3:0] to req0, req1, req2, req3 and the new string should appear like: [3:0] req0, [3:0] req1, [3:0] req2, [3:0] req3

Please help!

Comment: `String#split("\\s+")` and `String.replace(',',',')`.

Comment: I assume you have tried at least something then please share are the Community can easier correct, instead of letting us write the entire code. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String parts[] = myStr1.split("\\s+");

String prefix = parts[0];
StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer();

for(int i=1;i<parts.length;i++){
finalString.append(prefix);
finalString.append(parts[i]);
finalString.append(",");
}

System.out.print(finalString.toString());
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low-quality. Please add an explanation. Also, make sure you indent properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Eg:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Appending 
sb.append(token1); /what ever token you need.
sb.append(token3);
sb.append(token6);

//toString go get it in string format.
String finalString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I think the point of the question is more about the tokenizing than the appending. And anyway, when not in a loop, it's more readable to write `token1 + token3 + token6` - and the Java compiler will implement it internally using `StringBuilder` so it's no less efficient.